# Width ratio calculation is being applied twice

Tags: javascript, html

I am attempting to create an overlay which displays a larger version of an image when a thumbnail is clicked on. The problem I am running into is that the width of the image is being scaled down to far.

I am using the following code:

```
largeImage.addEventListener('load', function() {
    // Resize if Taller
    if (this.height > window.innerHeight) {
        this.ratio = window.innerHeight / this.height;
        this.height = window.innerHeight;
        this.width = this.width * this.ratio;
        console.log('Ratio: ' + this.ratio);
        console.log('Height: ' + this.height);
        console.log('Width: ' + this.width);
    }

    // Resize if Wider
    if (this.width > window.innerWidth) {
        this.ratio = window.innerWidth / this.width;
        this.height = this.height * this.ratio;
        this.width = this.width * this.ratio;
    }
}, false);
```

The image in question is 1000x1500 and the window.innerHeight and .innerWidth are 430px and 1064px respectively. this.ratio calculates out to 0.2866666666666667 so this.width should calculate to 287. But instead I am getting 82 which is 1000 * 0.2866666666666667 * 0.2866666666666667.

I put in the console.log for diagnostic reasons and this.height and this.ratio are being calculated correctly, but the width is being multiplied by the ratio twice somehow.

Edit: I updated the code to include the entire eventHandler.

Comment: are you calling the function twice by mistake/

Comment: There is a sister "if" statement that will check and see if the width of the image is wider than the screen. I commented it out and still had the same problem.

Comment: Not an answer, but you could simplify `this.height = this.height * this.ratio` to `this.height = window.innerHeight`.

Comment: is it possible that when you change this.height by this.ratio, the width to height is preserved and so it gets scaled down again? What if you just comment out the this.width = line?

Comment: @tofutim That is what I am wondering. Because that is the logical thing happening, but yet it makes no sense that an operation to change the height would also change the width.

Plus I want to make sure that this is something that will not come back to bite me on an older browser or something else.

Comment: @JosiahKeller I get the same result

Comment: Should it not be an 'if else' construction. If it is both wider and higher you might scale too much. Don't see anything else wrong though

Comment: @belinus Exaclty, it's a mathematical simplification.  It's supposed to give the same result, that's why I said it isn't an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The width of the image is automatically resized when you resize the height.

So, you resize the height by 0.2866666666666667 (but this also resizes the width) and then you apply 0.2866666666666667 again - that's why you get the ratio applied twice.

You can comment this line - you should get the values as expected in the console:

```
this.width = this.width * this.ratio;
```

Comment: Yeah, I just found that out while messing with the code. My question is now at one time the original code worked since it actually originates within a Lynda.Com course (I did notify the author). So my question now is: What changed to make it automatically do the width as well? And how would one go about changing one but not the other?

Comment: If the width and height are set in HTML for example, then changing one dimension won't adjust the other proportionally - this only happens when there's no width & height set beforehand.

Comment: Neither are specified in the HTML though. This is a brand new <img> element being created on the fly by the parent addEventListener which is a click on the thumbnail.

Comment: After digging around on MDN, I found the imgElement.naturalHeight and .naturalWidth properties and tried those and it worked just fine too.

Answer (score 0):

You need to compute the new height and width values ahead of time so neither is skewed by the changing of the other.

```js
function resize() {
  var element = document.getElementById('image');
  var newHeight = element.height * 0.5;
  var newWidth = element.width * 0.5;
  
  console.log('Original width and height: ', element.width, element.height);
  
  element.height = newHeight;
  element.width = newWidth;
  
  console.log('New width and height: ', element.width, element.height);
}
```

```html
<div>
  <button onclick="resize()">Shrink By 50%</button>
</div>
<img id="image" src="https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/07bb1a01c672794db448fdb8e180042e?s=328&d=identicon&r=PG&f=1" />
```